# Why does SignalR require adding response compression of type "application/octet-stream"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

This [Microsoft Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server#add-services-and-an-endpoint-for-the-signalr-hub-1) shows how to configure SignalR in a Blazor app. There's a step there that adds the response compression middleware for the `application/octet-stream` MIME type:

```
services.AddSignalR();
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
});
```

However, it can be noticed that this step is skipped in the article that shows [how to configure SignalR for an ASP.NET Core App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)(with the JavaScript library).

I'm trying to configure SignalR for an ASP.NET Core MVC app but it is in a prerendered Razor component, so I'm configuring it as demonstrated in the Blazor article. Other parts of my application involve uploading and downloading images and spreadsheets, so I would also like to know if adding the above response compression will interfere with these operations.

Could someone explain if and why this step is required? Does it make any significant difference?
I suppose it is to optimize the transmission of binary messages over the SignalR connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone explain if and why this step is required? Does it make
> any significant difference? I suppose it is to optimize the
> transmission of binary messages over the SignalR connection.

The Response Compression Middleware is not required when using asp.net core SignalR in the Blazor. In [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server#add-services-and-an-endpoint-for-the-signalr-hub-1), if you remove the `services.AddResponseCompression()` and `app.UseResponseCompression();` in the Startup.cs file, the SignalR still works well.

More detail information, you could check [the Response Compression Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-5.0), it is used to dynamically compress response bodies and reduce bandwidth utilization.